# Self made "Many1" parser

Tags: parsing, haskell

This is task from online course. I've been sitting on this for two days. Please give some explanation or hints to solve it.

Here's type

```
newtype Prs a = Prs { runPrs :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }
```

I need to implement `many1` parser. This is how it should work

```
> runPrs (many1 $ char 'A') "AAABCDE"
Just ("AAA","BCDE")
> runPrs (many1 $ char 'A') "BCDE"
Nothing
```

I have parser `many` implemented like that

```
many p = (:) <$> p <*> many p  <|> pure []
```

Here's output for previous example.

```
*Main> test9
Just ("AAA","BCDE")
*Main> test10
Just ("","BCDE")
```

Note last result, it returns empty string but `many1` should return `Nothing`. I don't know how to change `many` code to make work like `many1`. I can't undestand how to stop on first incorrect symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `many1` will need some way to fail: as you've written it it consumes characters for a while, consing them onto a pending result, until it eventually runs out of matches. This doesn't cover any cases where the parse could fail.

What you've implemented here is, in a way, `many0`, a parser which consumes 0 or more repetitions of something. Can you think of a way to implement `many1` in terms of `many0`? It will look something like:

1. Consume one instance of `p`, *without* an alternative in case that fails
2. Consume 0 or more instances of `p`, returning `[]` when that fails.

Or in Haskell,

```
many1 :: Prs a -> Prs [a]
many1 p = (:) <$> p <*> many0 p
```

Comment: Thank you, it works on example cases and now I got the idea. But unfortunetaly it fails on grading system in some other test.